# Painting a white Ikea desk to an oak colour?

Tags: furniture, repainting, ikea

I’ve had a white desk for a year but it doesn’t match the oak furniture in my room, I want to paint it but I am unsure about the correct steps as I have come across conflicting advice?
thanks

Comment: If you want it to look oak like, you do not want paint.  Can go cheap and use self sticking paper/film that looks like oak, or use veneer glue downed, sanded and finished.  The oak veneer is what is probably on most of your furniture now, unless you have real oak(expensive) furniture.

Comment: Paint will get you close in color, but won't give you any texture or the "pattern" of wood.  You may only be interested in color, which is fine, and in which case paint may be fine.  But you may find that high-wear spots allow the white to show through eventually.

Comment: If the furniture is melamine- or laminate-coated, not painted already (quite possible in modern furniture) then paint will have a hard time sticking. Lots of sanding to get the glossy finish off and then priming will be necessary.

Comment: Don't try to remove the white - the wood underneath will be manufactured chipboard and will look awful.    The quick and lazy answer is a tablecloth on top.

Answer (score 11):

White Ikea is almost certainly white melamine. That surface will have to be sanded to have any hope of paint sticking.

It's possible to achieve an "Oak" faux finish by painting, (sometimes referred to as "graining" since you are literally painting the "wood grain" as art) but it's a high-skill process. Expect to spend some time practicing before you get results that are acceptable.

You can also achieve an "Oak" real finish by laminating Oak veneer (very thin slices of real wood) onto the surface of the furniture, using contact cement.

The "easy" solution is to put your white Ikea furniture up for sale or give it away, and buy an oak desk.

Comment: Back during the 80s we refinished a dresser.  Forget now what the process was called but it combined two separate colours of paint so you got a wavy finish of the two colours.  Not quite a wood grain look, but was quite easy for non artist to do.

Comment: Two-tone "random" is pretty easy - I've done it with a wadded plastic bag for the second color, or a bath scrubber for a different look.

Comment: You can get these things which you waggle across the surface to make fake grain. I've never seen one outside a showroom that actually looked any good though, so I'm not volunteering it as an answer - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq8py.jpg

Comment: @crip659 We called it "antiquing the furniture" at our house.

Comment: @shoover  That does sound familiar.  It did turn out good in my eyes, blue with black highlights colour.